# Error on running Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, emulation

This is my first Android application which I am learning using [this series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUA_isgpTHI&feature=relmfu) and I get an error when I run the emulator.

Here's the program:

```
package com.thenewboston.android.sarabjeet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the run-time information and the error:

```
[2011-10-12 18:16:57 - sarabjeet] Android Launch!
[2011-10-12 18:16:57 - sarabjeet] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-12 18:16:57 - sarabjeet] Performing com.thenewboston.android.sarabjeet.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-10-12 18:16:57 - sarabjeet] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Sarabjeets_Phone' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-12 18:17:00 - sarabjeet] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-10-12 18:17:00 - sarabjeet] Starting activity com.thenewboston.android.sarabjeet.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-10-12 18:17:02 - sarabjeet] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.thenewboston.android.sarabjeet/.MainActivity }
[2011-10-12 18:17:02 - sarabjeet] **ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front**
```

I am totally new to Android programming and running the Emulator. What might be wrong here that I don't see the emulator as I should?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The real errors in your program will only be printed in the logcat. Read this to learn how to display the logcat content: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. The tools just saw that nothing changed in your program, so they didn't recompile your application into a new APK. They launched the already installed one on the emulator instead.

Sometimes the tools miss that you changed a resource (e.g. an image file inside the `/res` folder), in this case you can clean your project to force a regeneration. Use `Project -> Clean ..` inside eclipse for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

this is because already your application run in simulator press back button and again run and try OR go to setting first delete application and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Check the com.thenewboston.android.sarabjeet
Ensure that its in your manifest file
may be something like this...

```
<activity android:name="sarabjeet.MainActivity"></activity>
```

Or whatever your package is called :)

If all else fails, then delete the app from your simulator, then close down the emulator

press project > clean > clean all projects

Then load up the simulator again, all will be good

Looks like it may be that!

Post me your android manifest bit too :)